# SQL select query for ranking

Tags: sql, select

I have this table called `logs` that logs a who input or output data.
Now I wan't to get the statistics of who has the most contributions and rank them.

Columns are

```
 Occur_Time | iUser_id | iUsername | oUser_id | oUsername
 --iUser_id is the input persons index from another table that lists the username.
 --iUsername is the input persons name.
 --oUser_id is the index of the person who took the input away.
 --oUsername is the name of the person who took the input away.
```

Now I wan't to know who has the most input.

My logic:

```
 Example:
     User_id is 1, name is One.
     Check how many times 1 is repeated on iUser_id = 100 times.
     Check how many times 1 is repeated on oUser_id = 10 times.
     User_id=1 has contributed 90 times.
     Then sort by who has most contribution.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you create the table on sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(untested):

```
SELECT L.iUsername, 
((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM logs WHERE iUsername=L.iUsername) - 
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM logs WHERE oUsername=L.iUsername)) as rank  
FROM logs L 
GROUP BY L.iUsername 
ORDER BY rank ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Rank` feature is probably what you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx

Comment: I'm checking this now. I didn't even know rank() existed on sql. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try that query.

```
Select user_id, count(user_id) from tablename group by user_id;
```